# Asp.net Core MVC Render Body Problem after Implementing Responsive Side Bar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sidebar

After implementing sidebar its fridge my other page and didn't able to scroll the page in Asp.net Core MVC. I think the problem is comes from the _layout.cshtml file. as it has a container which render my other page. Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is My _Layout.cshtm File. The header is the side bar.

```
<header>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="logo_content">
                <div class="logo">
                    <i class='bx bxl-c-plus-plus'></i>
                    <div class="logo_name">dgInfoSys</div>
                </div>
                <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav_list">
                <li>
                    <i class='bx bx-search-alt'></i>
                    <input class="text" placeholder="Search...">
                    <span class="tooltip">Search</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                        <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
                </li>
                <li>


                    <a href="#">
                        <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
                        <span class="links_name">User</span>
                        <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down htmlcss-arrow arrow  '></i>
                    </a>

                    <span class="tooltip">User</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class='bx bxs-user-badge'></i>
                        <span class="links_name">Super Admin</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="tooltip">Super Admin</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class='bx bx-line-chart'></i>
                        <span class="links_name">Analytics</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="tooltip">Analytics</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a asp-controller="BTBTable" asp-action="Index">
                        <i class='bx bxs-report'></i>
                        <span class="links_name">Files</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="tooltip">Files</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class='bx bx-cog'></i>
                        <span class="links_name">Setting</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="tooltip">Setting</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="profile_content">
                <div class="profile">
                    <div class="profile_details">
                        @*<img src="" alt="" />*@
                        <div class="name_job">
                            <div class="name">Masum Rayhan</div>
                            <div class="job">Developer</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <i class='bx bx-log-out' id="log_out"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
         <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; 
         </span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
         <main role="main" class="pb-3">
               @RenderBody()
         </main>
    </div>
```

And side bar css is given below:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 78px;
    /*width: 240px;*/
    background: #11101d;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

    .sidebar.active {
        width: 240px;
    }

.sidebar .logo_content .logo {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.active .logo_content .logo {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.logo_content .logo i {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.logo_content .logo .logo_name {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.sidebar #btn {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    top: 6px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.sidebar.active #btn {
    left: 90%;
}

.sidebar ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

    .sidebar ul li {
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 5px;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

        .sidebar ul li .tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            left: 122px;
            height: 35px;
            width: 122px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            border-radius: 6px;
            line-height: 35px;
            text-align: center;
            background: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0s;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

.sidebar.active ul li .tooltip {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar ul li:hover .tooltip {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50%
}

.sidebar ul li input {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: #1d1b31;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}

.sidebar ul li .bx-search {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

    .sidebar ul li .bx-search:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #1d1b31;
    }

.sidebar ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border-radius: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

    .sidebar ul li a:hover {
        color: #11101d;
        background: #fff;
    }

    .sidebar ul li a i {
        height: 50px;
        min-width: 50px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

.sidebar .links_name {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.active .links_name {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.sidebar .profile_content {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

    .sidebar .profile_content .profile {
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px 6px;
        height: 60px;
        background: none;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }

.sidebar.active .profile_content .profile {
    background: #1d1b31;
}

.profile_content .profile .profile_details {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar.active .profile .profile_details {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.profile .profile_details img {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.profile .profile_details .name_job {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.profile .profile_details .name {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.profile .profile_details .job {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.profile #log_out {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    min-width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    background: #1d1b31;
}

.sidebar.active .profile #log_out {
    left: 80%
}

.sidebar.active .profile #log_out {
    background: none;
}

.home_content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% -78px);
    left: 78px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

    .home_content .text {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #1d1b31;
        margin: 12px;
    }

.sidebar.active ~ .home_content {
    width: calc(100% -240px);
    left: 240px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Css code:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `overflow` property specifies whether to clip the content or to add scrollbars when the content of an element is too big to fit in the specified area

The `overflow` property has the following values:

- `visible` - Default. The overflow is not clipped. The content renders
  outside the element's box
- `hidden` - The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will
  be invisible
- `scroll` - The overflow is clipped, and a scrollbar is added to see
  the rest of the content
- `auto` - Similar to scroll, but it adds scrollbars only when
  necessary

So in your code, you just need to delete `overflow: hidden;` or change it as the property whtich you need.